# Why is Grid.Row attached property specified without any enclosing Grid?

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I am reading code from a [WPF project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54472/Defining-WPF-Adorners-in-XAML) which has the following XAML code (I have omitted the boilerplate parts):

```
<Window x:Class="AdornedControlSample.Window1"
    ...
    x:Name="window"
    ...
    >
    <Canvas
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="canvas"
        >
    ...
```

Please note that there is *no* `Grid` defined whatsoever anywhere in this XAML file.  So, my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of the `Grid.Row="1"` within the `Canvas` definition?
2. What purpose does `x:Name="window"` serve?  I have not seen anything in the code-behind that references a `window`. (There are references to `Window1`, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

In your example, `Grid.Row` has no purpose at all. You gave it a value, but that value will not be used because there is no `Grid` around the `Canvas`. It also doesn't give an error because it is a valid property/value. 
The `RowProperty` is defined in the `Canvas` class.

**Question 2**

It gives a unique name (within the window itself) to the UI-element. For now, it has no purpose. So you can remove it safely. However, if you want to access the window in the code-behind of the view, the `x:name` serves a purpose. But you can also access the window via the `this` keyword.

Comment: +1 I see, so  I can list attached properties and they will only be activated if there is an enclosing control of that type?

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes, they will:)